# How to list all enabled services from systemctl?

Tags: services, systemd

How can I list all `enabled` services from `systemctl`?

I know running `systemctl` command by itself lists all services, but I would like to only get the `enabled` ones.

Comment: what do you mean by enabled? You mean services that are running?

Comment: @Gen enabling a service is quite different from starting it. See `man systemctl`.

Comment: Fascinating.  The lowest rated answer is the most "correct" answer, even though it is clearly not the best answer.  This excellent question (and its answers) is an interesting example of how systemd violates the long-standing (and brilliant)  design principles of Unix & Co.  @FelipeAlvarez complains that the most-accepted answer assumes systemd follows the unix design philosopy, but systemd/systemctl can do exactly what he wants (most experienced users will just consider that complete bloat).  I begin to see more clearly why Linus Torvalds is so vehemently critical of systemd.

Comment: If you want to list "templated" services (blabla@instance.service), do not forget to add "--all" - thanks to @rafdouglas below.

Comment: @BISI is the lowest rated answer today still the answer that was lowest rated when you wrote your comment - or, iow, which answer do you think is the correct one?

Answer (score 773, accepted):

`systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled` will list all *enabled* ones.

If you want which ones are currently *running*, you need `systemctl | grep running`.

Use the one you're looking for.  Enabled, doesn't mean it's running.  And running doesn't mean it's enabled.  They are two different things.

Enabled means the system will run the service on the next boot.  So if you enable a service, you still need to manually start it, or reboot and it will start.

Running means it's actually running right now, but if it's not enabled, it won't restart when you reboot.

Comment: annoying to have to use an external tool (grep) to show this vital information. But thank you for showing us the way :)

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez You're welcome!  However, grep is not an external tool, it's a base command.  You could always write your own scripts with simpler names that will run those commands for you.  I do this often myself.

Comment: Grep is not systemctl, so the OS has to make another call to another tool.  That's what I meant :-) One tool (systemctl) should do one job, very, very well.

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Correct.  But that's how Linux works.  Many small binaries that work well with each other.  systemctl does what is asked, it lists services.  There is no filtering command built-in to systemctl because grep already exists and can do that well with any program's output.  It's how it's always been :)

Comment: I agree and so it should be. But, systemd already tries to do SO much that I wonder why it can't list enabled services?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Linux is all about small tools, and it's part of Linux's philosophy which was inherited from Unix : "Make each program do one thing well. To do a new job, build afresh rather than complicate old programs by adding new "features"." - [The Bell System Technical Journal from 1978](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)

Comment: `systemctl | grep running` do not list anything to me! Even if something is running is only listed as for his status like: `enabled, disabled, masked, static`

Comment: +1 I was able to grep systemctl to see if mysql service was running using `systemctl | grep -E 'running.*active|active.*running' | grep mys`

Comment: @Cirelli94 That is odd. `systemctl` with no other options shows an output where the 4th column states if something is running/failed/exited etc.  Are you sure you're running Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 You don't even need that much, you can just do `systemctl | grep mysql` to see if it's running.

Comment: Simpler: `systemctl list-unit-files --state=running`

Comment: It appears that `systemctl list-unit-files` does not list ALL serivces.  For example, it does not list `tinc`, even though tinc is enabled.  Maybe `systemctl list-unit-files` only lists services that have unit files?  But fails to lists any services that might be enabled via legacy sysv style init scripts?

Comment: grepping the output of systemctl seems to produce a mess of lines broken in weird places...

Comment: @TomH No issues here on 16.04 or 17.10 or 18.04.  Verify your installation.

Comment: In general, the names of unit files do not have to be the same as the names of units. For example on 18.04 there is a unit file `sshd.service`, but the unit is actually called `ssh.service`. Same with service templates.

Comment: This does not work for *instances* that take an argument, e.g. you may have `my@x.service` enabled and `my@y.service` disabled. All you will see from `systemctl list-unit-files` is `my@.service indirect` which is useless.

Comment: @Walf try to add `--all` to systemctl command .

Comment: @digital_infinity that made no difference to instances.

Comment: @Walf I used `--all` with instances after I had made them them enabled to list status of all instances or start them all. Did use wildcards ? (`systemctl list-unit-files 'my@*' --all`)

Comment: @Walf Now I can see `--all` works correctly with `status` but does not work with `list-unit-files`

Comment: No systemd unit file must ever contain the string "running" or "enabled". `long_running_backup.service` or `gpu_enabled_calculation.service` will lead to bugs in the future. – Unix philosophy at its best.

Comment: To make it a bit more robust: add parameter `--no-legend` to systemctl and `-w` to grep.

Answer (score 191):

`man systemctl` states:

> `--state=`
>
> The argument should be a comma-separated list of unit `LOAD`, `SUB`, or `ACTIVE` states. When listing units, show only those in the specified states. Use `--state=failed` to show only failed units.

Explanation:

`LOAD`: Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
`ACTIVE`: The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of `SUB`.
`SUB`: The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

Though you can also use this to only show `enabled` units with:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled
```

If a unit is `enabled` that means that the system will start it on startup. Though setting something to `enabled` doesn't actually also `start` it so you will need to do that manually, or reboot the system after setting it to `enabled`.

Comment: To enable and start at the same time: `systemctl enable --now ...`

Comment: `--state=enabled` has no effect on systemd version 215 (on Raspbian 8 Jessie), but it does work on systemd version 229 (on Ubuntu 16.04.03 Xenial).

Comment: @mpb: But yet it works perfectly fine on version 235 on Arch Linux.

Comment: You can also check `--state=generated` for generated unit files that might be running (the pihole-FTL service works this way, for example).

Comment: 1. The answer lacks of a `--type service` to filter only that type of units. 2. @mgalgs `list-unit-files` [now includes](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-May/042555.html) generated units

Comment: You don't have the service(s) if they are based on a template `servicename@.service` while `--list-units` does

Answer (score 100):

To list all the `systemd` service which are in `state=active` and `sub=running`

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running
```

To list all the `systemd` serice which are in `state=active` and sub either running or exited

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --state=active
```

Comment: `--list-units` show the service(s) if they are based on a template `servicename@.service`  +1

Answer (score 23):

To see 'enabled' services including these that are still under upstart/init run:

```
systemctl list-unit-files --type service --state enabled,generated
```

To see all of the currently running services run:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --state running
```

Comment: Unfortunately the names of the services can be different in the two lists - e.g. `sshd` vs. `ssh` and `syslog` vs. `rsyslog`.

Comment: The only "non grep" right answer. Though not sure why upstart is mentioned...

Comment: `list-unit-files` [now includes](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2019-May/042555.html) generated units

Answer (score 15):

There is a good GUI application called Stacer where you can manage all the services.

[image]

Check its Github link [Stacer Github](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer)
Also check [Web](https://oguzhaninan.github.io/Stacer-Web/) for more info

Comment: This is brilliant! I used this command to install on Debian/Unbuntu: `sudo apt-get install stacer`

Answer (score 11):

Also overview of all active and failed services:

```
systemctl list-units --type service --state running,failed
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the current answers, I use the following to get just the names of the services:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --state=active,running | awk '/.*\.service/ {print $1}'
```

Rather than the tabular format, this makes it easier to pipe just those services to another program

Answer (score 2):

## What about systemctl unit templates?

To list also templated units, you might want to use:

`systemctl list-units --all|grep yourservice`

The `--all` switch shows also all units which have been instantiated with

`systemctl <service_name>@<argument>.service`

From the man page:

> When listing units with list-units, also show inactive units and units
> which are following other units. When showing unit/job/manager
> properties, show all properties regardless whether they are set or
> not.

Example:

`systemctl openvpn@my_office_endopoint.service`

Further reading:
https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-template-unit-files/

Comment: The "--all" parameter was missing from other replies!

Answer (score 2):

This for me has been the fastest way to check my running or failed services that are supposed to be enabled. With this, I know *I do not have to run*:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

I just use most of the above with comma separation on state:

```
systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running,enabled,failed,generated
```

Answer (score 1):

To list **user `otheruser`'s** active **user** services:

```
sudo runuser -l otheruser-c "systemctl --user list-units --type=service --state=active"
```