# Save/export/import services settings of systemd?

Tags: boot, 18.04, systemd

The question here is not about the services on the system. But the settings of systemd itself.
Which service to auto-start at boot? Which one don't?

I tried looking around my system, and using internet search but as one might suspect, this is not a simple thing to word in Google.

Comment: `systemctl` is the command. See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/795226/how-to-list-all-enabled-services-from-systemctl

Comment: @Rinzwind - Thank you. Is it possible to somehow export this "status" / setup?