# Run AIDE at the selected time of the week

Tags: 18.04, schedule

How can I configure aide linux to start at the selected time of the week,
e.g. on Sundays at 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `which aide` and copy the result (assuming `/usr/bin/aide`)

Add a line to `crontab -e`  with format

```
0 9 * * Sun /usr/bin/aide --check
```

OR to `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 9 * * Sun {user} /usr/bin/aide --check
```

- (1st 5: minutes, hours, day of month, month, day)
- replace {user} by your username
- Sun can be replaced by either 0 or 7.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JlPqMppN9jSeMkUlDbzsIYQ0rblXjYAv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: such an entry in crontab is ok?

Comment: yes, for /etc/crontab if you want to test crontabs entries: https://crontab.guru/ :)

Comment: why despite the changes crontab today aide started?

Comment: because you have something else that starts it? Like a service?

Comment: How to check service?

Comment: How to check service?

Comment: you really should know how to check that.  see for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/795226/how-to-list-all-enabled-services-from-systemctl

Comment: Aide has also started today. As in the picture you can see. I mean, I have to change the entry to the one in the top-process?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UN-cMR7WnDpAX-JhAhs5IvzUxgEsth7Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I still run the AIDE process every day, despite crontab asking for help what I did wrong. In the attachment there is a photo from "crontab -e".

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EsRbk59GZui8exjiulqAug5s_HMuIYwF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what process runs AIDE check? An entry in crontab does not help.